# How to access AppSync API using custom Federated Identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I'm trying to consume AWS AppSync API using Federated Identities with custom authenticated role but without success.

First, I followed this [tutotial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-node.html) to create my client. Then I opened Federated Identities console -> Edit identity pool -> Custom and created a `Developer provider name`: `login.mycompany.myapp` and checked `Enable access to unauthenticated identities`.

After, I followed this [one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) to know how to create custom authentication.

> Once you obtain an identity ID and session token from your backend,
>   you will to pass them into the AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials
>   provider. Here's an example:
>
> ```
> AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({   
>     IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',    
>     IdentityId: 'IDENTITY_ID_RETURNED_FROM_YOUR_PROVIDER',
>     Logins: {
>         'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': 'TOKEN_RETURNED_FROM_YOUR_PROVIDER'    
>     }
> });
> ```

How can I get `IDENTITY_ID_RETURNED_FROM_YOUR_PROVIDER`, `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com` and `IDENTITY_ID_RETURNED_FROM_YOUR_PROVIDER`? I saw how to do it:

> You obtain a token by calling GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity. This API must be invoked from your backend using AWS developer credentials.

I checked `GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity` [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) and I created this piece of code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region

const cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();

const params = {
    IdentityPoolId: IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
    Logins: {
        'login.mycompany.myapp': 'sometoken',
    },
};

cognitoidentity.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(params, function(
    err,
    { IdentityId, Token }
) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(IdentityId, Token);
}
```

I got `IdentityId` and `Token`. I took these variables and created a Cognito client as follow:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    IdentityId: IdentityId,
    Logins: {
        'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com': Token,
    },
});

const credentials = AWS.config.credentials;

const AWSAppSyncClient = require('aws-appsync').default;
const AUTH_TYPE = require('aws-appsync/lib/link/auth-link').AUTH_TYPE;

// Set up Apollo client
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: GRAPHQL_API_URL,
    region: REGION,
    auth: {
        type: AUTH_TYPE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS,
        credentials: credentials,
    },
});
```

Now, when I make a query

```
client.hydrated().then(function(client) {
    //Now run a query
    client
        .query({ query: query })
        .then(function logData(data) {
            console.log('results of query: ', data);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

I get the error: `Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 401`. Am I missing some configuration?

Thank you!

**Edit**: At Federated Identities, I set `Unauthenticated role` and `Authenticated role` as follow:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "appsync:GraphQL",
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "appsync:GraphQL",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:appsync:*:*:apis/*/types/*/fields/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "appsync:GraphQL",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:appsync:*:*:apis/*"
        }
    ]
}
```